# LARAVEL Enviar parametros al metodo create

Tags: laravel, controller, get

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web y necesito enviar parámetros al método **create** de un controlador, para que al variar el parámetro le pase me devuelva otros parámetros. Tengo entendido que los métodos de los controladores ya tienen definidos según la url que se pase, pero tampoco puedo generar métodos propios para llamarlos.

Dejo un detalle de mi código, espero que puedan ayudarme.

**Link de la vista**

```
<a href="{{route('Compras.create',$idProv)}}" class='btn btn-outline-primary'>Nuevo</a>
```

**Controlador**

```
public function Create(Request $request){
    $pr='';
    $cb='';
    $cp='';
    if($request->idProv==''){
        $pr=Proveedore::all();
    }else{
        $pr=Proveedore::findOrFail($request->idProv);
        $cb=ct_bancaria::find($request->idProv)->Cuentas_Bancarias;
        $cp=computadora::all();
    }
    return view("Compras.create",compact('pr','cb','cp'));
}
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::resource('/Compras', 'ControllerCompras');
```

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor el error?

Comment: Por defecto laravel en el metodo create no recibe parametros de tipo request aparte no se si influya pero tienes `Create` mas no `create`, lo que deberias hacer es crear tu propia ruta

Comment: Como te indican debes agregar tu propia ruta, seria de tipo `Get` por lo que debes recibir el atributo directamente no de tipo `Request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun entiendo quizas debas usar un parametro con nombre en route()

```
route('/Compras/create',["idProv" => $idProv])
```

Y usar `public function create` (con minuscula) para declarar la funcion

Comment: No hace falta declarar la ruta en el método `route` de la forma en que lo haces, en cambio se pasa el valor directo como lo tiene el op: `Compras.create`

Comment: Buenas, perdon por responder tarde, estuve con mucho trabajo. Al final si me resulto como dijiste. Para enviarle parametros al **Request** , necesitaba declarar el nombre  **"idProv"** y despues asignarle el valor con **=>**.
Ahora me encuentro en otro drama. Al principio me pasa un array despues no se que tipo de dato me devuelve con **findOrFail**